# ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object - laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to obtain the "ID" and "name" fields from a pivot table, I tried this:

```
public function Display(){

$langservice = new langService(); 

$musgroups=$langservice->getMusgroup(session()->get('lang_id'));

               foreach($musgroups as $musgroup1){
                    foreach($musgroup1 as $musgroup){

                        echo 'name:'+$musgroup->name;
                    }
                }
```

But this error appears "Trying to get property of non-object" I tried to "print_r($musgroups);" but it displays all the information in a loop (12 times exactly)

Comment: try this `if (!empty($musgroup->name)) {echo 'name:'+$musgroup->name; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: `'name:'+$musgroup->name;` is not how you concatenate strings in PHP either

Comment: why are you doing a double foreach?

Comment: Not sure at all, is not only my code. I think that was trying things and that was ass far as he went